# Why is the . (dot) directory from "ansible-galaxy" command removed when using - Jenkins docker image

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-container, ansible-galaxy

I'm trying to create a custom docker image using a `Dockerfile`. In my Dockerfile I have installed ansible and I can confirm this works from earlier experience, but when I am using the command `ansible-galaxy` to install a specific `role` or `collection` (collection in this case) it is NOT stored in the installed path.

**OUTPUT FROM DOCKER BUILD:**

```
(Previous steps works)
     ...
Step 11/11 : RUN ansible-galaxy collection install community.vmware
 ---> Running in e222fee67b89
Process install dependency map
Installing 'community.vmware:1.1.0' to '/home/me/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/vmware'
```

When I try to run a container from this image the path `/home/me/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/vmware` does not exists, so after running the container I have to use the `docker exec` and manually run the command `ansible-galaxy collection install community.vmware`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running the `ansible-galaxy` command when building the image itself, I pull the ansible collection to my computer from GitHub and copy the collection to `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/`. Following the [Jenkins docker documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#script-usage).

```
COPY .ansible/collection  /usr/share/jenkins/ref/
```

The jenkins docker image is built with a script which copies the files from the  `/usr/share/jenkins/ref/` directory to the jenkins home directory.